# Can I use a batch file to call git bash and then pass commands to it?

Tags: bash, batch-file

What I want to do is have a .bat file that would open git bash and change the directory to my local repository:

I thought that this would open up the exe and then pass the command but it didn't:
`"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" --cd D:\Dev\`

Any idea if that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to change directory to the folder you want first, and then run it:

```
C:
cd \path\to\dir1
start "" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Comment: When you provide the `/D` switch to `cd`, you can chage the current drive *and* directory at once: `cd /D "C:\path\to\dir1"`. This should work also: `start "" /D "C:\path\to\dir1" "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login`.